# issue fetching more records using recordset

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I am haveing a classic asp applicaiton that  can fetch and display records from sql server database.

I am getting "page cannot be displayed" error when the query returns more than 9000 records. If it is less than 9000 records there are no issues in the applicaiton. I belive this should be some settings issue somewhere. Can anyone suggest me what might be the issue ?

I am using a recordset to fetch the data.

thanks in advance.

Regards,
jebli

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to help you if you had an error message.

Turn off `"friendly error messages"` in your web browser and enable `"send detailed error message to client"` on the web server.

This allows you to see exactly why the server is complaining.